# mistake in the code（find prime number from1 to 100）

Tags: c++

I think it's right,but it can't find the prime number.I don't know what mistakes it have.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, a[101];
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    a[1] = 0;
    for (i = 2; i < sqrt(100); i++);
    for (j = i + 1; j <= 100; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 0 && a[j] != 0)
            if (a[j] % a[i] == 0)
                a[j] = 0;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != 0)cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

it output all the numbers from 2 to 99 ,not the prime numbers

Comment: see that semicolon after your second for-loop?

Comment: `for (i = 2; i < sqrt(100); i++);` don't do an awful lot, innit. Use braces; everywhere, not just where you really need them.

Comment: oh I know ,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer `for` loop doesn't have a body.

`for (i = 2; i < sqrt(100); i++);`

Get rid of the semicolon. Always use `curly braces` to mark the boundaries of your loops even if the loop body is just a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have inputed "for (i = 2; i < sqrt(100); i++);" and the code line run, not having a body. It only loops several times and finishes.
Because of ";" last.
If you delete the character ";" it can run well.